# Swift 3/4 AVAudioPlayer:contentsOf: fails when loading same URL many times

Tags: swift, url, audio, avaudioplayer

I am working on a simple game in Swift 4, Xcode 9 Beta 6, and I get an error when attempting to load an Audio File from the same URL many times. Let me show you what I mean; I have a code that looks a little like this.

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundName, withExtension: ext) else {
    return nil
}

do {

    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    player.prepareToPlay()

} catch let error {
    print("Could not create AVAudioPlayer with url: \(url.absoluteString)")
    return nil
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription")
}
```

Note: `soundName` and `ext` are `String` objects composing the name of the **local** audio file. `player` is a property of the type AVAudioPlayer.

The game creates a sound using this code, which works perfectly at first, but after a while, it kind of gets lazy and the `player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)` fails and prints: 
`Could not create AVAudioPlayer with url: url here` 
`Error: The operation couldn't be completed. (NSOSStatusErrorDomain error -42.)`

Anyone has any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

I loaded the content of the URL into a Data object by using `let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)` and that seems to have fix the issue. I am not making it as resolved because I still wish to know what is wrong with using just a URL and why it stops working after loading the same URL several times. Additionally, loading the contents into a binary Data object first might take more resources and time?